# Diagnostics and assumptions for Fractional Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, quasi-likelihood

I am investigating the effects of Variable X on Y'. Y' is a bounded, non-negative integer. So I have divided Y' by its upper bound to obtain a fraction Y which is in [0,1].

I am following a study where the investigated the effects of X on Y using a fractional logit regression.

However, I am unsure on what diagnostics and model assumptions I need to use? So far I have looked at Cook's distance and Hat Values. I have had trouble finding a resource that details the model requirements for this fractional logit regression.

Any help is much appreciated!